# Elasticsearch:Search with specific index type is 3 time slower than no index type specified

Tags: elasticsearch

Version 2.0rc1
Hardware; Core I5 ,8GB of Ram and SSD

Here I have index:user and type:test with 40m documents index.

```
query1: /user/test/_search?q=title:how to install window10
```

take around 2300ms to 2500ms

```
 query2: /user/_search?q=title:how to install window10
```

take around 700ms to 800ms

This is normal behavior of elasticsearch? or bug on 2.0 version?

Comment: I would have imagined this should, actually, be quite the opposite: if your index had more types I would have expected the query without _type specified would take longer than the query with the _type. If you execute the query two times, three times, do you get the same response times?

Comment: For single index with single type as above question: the response time still the same no whether how many times I executed the query. for 200 million docs, execute query with no specific type is 3 to 5 times faster than specified type. Not sure with multiple types index. But I think there is no reason to slow in case of single index and single type. I've test with 1.7 version, the same result.